# If $\mathbf{a}$ was an isolated point of some set $D$ where a function is defined, how does it make the function to have a limit (in a vector space)?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, vector-spaces

I can't understand this intuition. So, my book argues this is valid by using the fact that $P\to Q$ is always true if $P$ is false. The book says this along the lines of 'since we can't find any point on the domain that satisfies the limit criterion, the limit criterion is satisfied.' I am fine with using the logic of $P \to Q$ but graphically, it still doesn't make sense.

Say if I make the $\epsilon>0$ small enough for $||\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{L}||<\epsilon$ such that $\mathbf{x}$ must reside in the open ball of radius $\delta>0$ centered at $\mathbf{a}$. But if that $\delta >0$ is too small, I can't find $\mathbf{x}$ in the domain to satisfy the limit criterion given that $\mathbf{a}$ is an isolated point.

But what if for the function that becomes farther from the what seemed like a limit as the $\mathbf{x}$ gets within $\delta>0$ of the isolated point? That is, for the function that its values never reside in within $\epsilon>0$ from what seemed like a limit. For such function, we would know that as $\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{a}$, $\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{a}}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$ does not exist but once we choose to make $\mathbf{a}$ as an isolated point for $\delta>0$ just big enough to deceive us to believe that function has limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the value $L$ being a limit of the function $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ at a point $a$ is in logical terms the following statement:
$$\forall \epsilon>0\; \exists \delta>0\; \forall x\in D\setminus\{a\}: \left|x-a\right|<\delta\implies \left|f(x)-L\right|<\epsilon.$$
If $a$ is isolated, there exists some fixed $\delta>0$ such that there are no points $x\in D\setminus\{a\}$ with $\left|x-a\right|<\delta$. Then for this $\delta$, the statement $\left|x-a\right|<\delta$ is always false, so the implication is always true. Thus the above logical proposition is true, and by definition $L$ is a limit, no matter what happens to $f$ outside of the $\delta$-neighborhood of $a$.